# Finding greatest common divisor (assignment misgraded, I desperately need your help)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had an assignment (homework) as follows:

> Write a program which enters two positive integers a and b from the
>   keyboard. Also write a recursive function for determining the gcd
>   (greatest common divisor) of a and b using Euclid’s algorithm.
>   According to this algorithm if the first number is divisible by the
>   second one then thesecond one is the gcd. If this is not the case then
>   the gcd of the second number and the remainder of a=b has to be
>   determined. The result should be printed on the screen outside of the
>   function.

Here is my solution:

```
a=int(input("Enter the first number: "))
b=int(input("Enter the second number: "))

def GCDfinder(m,n):
    z=abs(m-n)
    if (m-n)==0:
        return n
    else:
        return GCDfinder(z,min(m,n))

print (GCDfinder(a,b))
```

I got 50% for this answer. I think the teacher's assistant who graded this does not know about what she does. Her comment is as follows:

> That is not the method described in the assignment. You should first
>   check if a%b==0 then return b. Or return gcd(b, a%b) Also check that
>   the input is positive and a>b

1-) The method that I used was based on Euclid's theorem. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

2-) There is absolutely no need to check a>b and there is also no need to check whether the input is positive or not, because I used abs()

Didn't TA misgrade the assignment? Or am I wrong?

Comment: `the gcd of the second number and the remainder of a=b` <- did you mean `a/b` instead of `a=b`?

Comment: It is her comment. It is not something that I wrote. I have no idea about what she is talking. Do you see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: You should check if input is positive. Your algorithm will never converge if n is negative.

Comment: But the assignment question does not tell me to check if n is negative. Therefore I assumed the inputs would be valid.

Comment: GCD is defined on positive integers in general case. It can be modified to handle negative numbers and if you calculate using remainder(%) then it will work, but with subtraction as you implemented it will not converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While what you've implemented is indeed a GCD finder, it's not Euclid's algorithm

This is what you've done:

```
if the two numbers are equal
    return either one as the GCD
else
    return the GCD of the absolute difference between them and the smaller number
```

Your algorithm finds the GCD by repetitive subtraction. While this is not wrong, it is certainly not Euler's algorithm (it's close, though).

Euler's algorithm does:

```
if the smaller number perfectly divides the larger
    return the smaller number as the GCD
else
    return the GCD of 
        1. the remainder from dividing the bigger number by the smaller
        2. the smaller number
```

Because Euclid's algorithm uses the modulus operator, it goes through far fewer steps, while in fact computing the same thing that your algorithm does. As a result, it is more efficient.

Here is an implementation of Euclid's algorithm:

```
def GCDfinder(a,b):
    while b != 0:
        a,b = b, a%b
    return a

>>> GCDfinder(12,20)
4
>>> GCDfinder(17,20)
1
>>> GCDfinder(3,4)
1
```

Comment: I think its still Euclid's algorithm. Subtraction is method of performing division and remainder on machine without division and remainder ops. It will be slower off course but its still emulating the same alog.

Comment: @Rohit: the two methods are *equivalent*, but not *identical*

Comment: FWIW, using the remainder is an efficiency enhancement to Euclid's algorithm.  Euclid almost certainly used subtraction rather than divide, and that's how the algorithm is always described in layman's terms.

Answer (score 2):

I truly think you and TA are both right. However because he/she is TA, he is a little more right. ;)

let me explain:

You are right because you perfectly succeeded in writing a program that determines the GCD.
However, the TA is right because you didn't follow the steps of the assignment, which in this case is leading.

Comparison:
That fact that you got 50% implies that although you fixed the problem (finding the GCD), you did not follow the rules. Compare it to a scavenger hunt. To complete it, you must follow all steps in the directions. However what you did here is the equivalent of overhearing someone talk about the location of the finishline, and then going to the finish line directly, not learning anything from the challenges/puzzles along the intended way

Comment: But my solution is based on Euclid's theorem, isn't it?

Comment: Your solution is based in Euclid's algorithm with small trick, you are using subtraction to calculate remainder. It will take more steps/function calls to converge, but essentially it is doing what Euclid's algo will do.

Comment: @Rakanoth: It's one interpretation of it. So is the way that you were *supposed* to do it.

Comment: After you edited your message yesterday, you helped me realize that you did not really understand my solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive implementation of Euclid's algorithm:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b==0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)
```

That is based on the pseudocode from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations